# Seasonality estimation without knowing the number of observations per seasonal cycle

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, python, seasonality

I'm trying to detect if there's any pattern (seasonality) between login attempts on a machine using python.
After researching a little bit i stumbled upon the library **pmdarima**, providing statistical tests such as the Canova-Hansen test to estimate the seasonal differencing term.

All the tests however requires knowing apriori the parameter **m** which indicates the number of observations per seasonal cycle.
However data are observed all the time every millisecond therefore one day i could have 500 logins, another day i could have 70 logins and another one none at all.

let's say i want to test seasonality in one month period, or one week period,how should i go about selecting the coefficient for the test?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @RichardHardy unfortunatly it could be useful for R but i think a python implementation could be troublesome as pointed out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464805/findfrequency-spec-ar-equivalent-in-python

Comment: While implementation is mostly off topic here, hopefully the statistical reasoning in the linked thread addresses your question.